# Saving utf-8 array in database laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have problem with saving utf-8 array in database with laravel.
when i save array in database it is stored like this

```
\u10e4\u10dd\u10dd\u10d3
```

when i display data it works fine, but when i run search query it displays nothing. 
database encoding is utf-8 with general_ci collation.
i've already tried to encode data before saving in database

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

any ideas?

Comment: You're probably searching by the string instead of its unicode representation, try with your string wrapped by `utf8_encode()`. If that doesn't work, post your database insert code and your fetch code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: I tried i, but same result.
I have 
`<input type="text" name="name[]">`
and in controller simple code 
`$data = Request::all(); Item::create($data)`

Comment: Check your DB and table call collation (should be set to utf8)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin database encoding is utf-8 and collation utf8_general_ci.
when i save string in another column in same table it displays normal string not like this 
`\u10e4\u10dd\u10dd\u10d3`

Comment: Please paste the code that you're using to add and fetch from the database.

Comment: insert code i've already commented, this is search query:
`$q = Input::get('q'); 
$item = Item::where('name', 'LIKE', '$q')->get();`

Comment: Remove the quotes around '$q', if you're trying to search by $q's value instead the string '$q'.

Comment: @jakub_jo i typed code wrong.. i have without quotes but nothing appears

Comment: Mysql has problem with null values. make sure that the name column that you are doing a "LIKE" operation on it, does not have any null value.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing these arrays in your database using the PHP [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php) function instead of encoding for JSON.

```
serialize($data);
```

When you want to use the data back, simply deserialize the array with PHP [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php) function.

```
unserialize($data);
```